# Can not find the correct Mime Type/Handler combination. (IIS 8.0 500 error .json files with PHP code in them)

Tags: php, json, iis-8

I have been asked to move an Zend Server Apache/PHP/MySQL site (that I did not create) to an IIS 8 web site. PHP/MySQL are both up and working.

However, the site has PHP code in .json files. I can not find the correct Mime Type/Handler combination to have these files run the PHP code. Instead I get an HTTP Error 500 with no additional details.

This is what is configured on the current server where it works.

```
LoadModule zend_enabler_module "C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\bin\ZendEnablerApache.dll"
ZendEnablerConfig "C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\etc\ZendEnablerConf.xml"
AddHandler zend-enabler-script .php .json
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .json
```

code sample:

```
    <?php 
// ## Autoloader ####
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/classes/AutoLoader/AutoLoader.php');
// ## /Autoloader ####
$session            = new \Session\Session();
$pageMgmt           = new \PageMgmt\PageMgmt();
$Authenticator      = new \UserMgmt\Authentication\Authentication();

$method = $_POST;

if (!isset($method) || !$method)
{
    $pageMgmt->renderJSON('0', 'Error: Invalid request method. Please try again!', $payload = NULL, $terminate = TRUE);
}

if (!array_key_exists('userName', $method) || empty($method['userName']))
{
    $pageMgmt->renderJSON('0', 'Error: Required variable missing: Username. Please contact the HelpDesk for assistance.', $payload = NULL, $terminate = TRUE);
}

if (!array_key_exists('passWord', $method) || empty($method['passWord']))
{
    $pageMgmt->renderJSON('0', 'Error: Required variable missing: Username. Please contact the HelpDesk for assistance.', $payload = NULL, $terminate = TRUE);
}

$Authenticator->setLogin_Username($method['userName']);
$Authenticator->setLogin_Password($method['passWord']);

if ($Authenticator->loginUser() === TRUE)
{
    $pageMgmt->renderJSON('1', 'Transaction executed successfully; Login complete.', $payload = NULL, $terminate = TRUE);
} else {
    $pageMgmt->renderJSON('0', 'Transaction failed; unable to login. Please contact the HelpDesk for assistance.', $payload = NULL, $terminate = TRUE);
}   
?>
```

Let me know if there is additional information that would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is a .json file. It works on the Zend Server. I will check to see if there is a rewrite rule. Thank you.

Comment: can you also post a sample json file as well?

Comment: It's not really a JSON file, it's a PHP file that produces JSON output. If they're all like this you could probably rename them all to .php without any problems.

Comment: Hi, Cemal, The above is the sample .json file.

Comment: Sorry Nick, the besides just renaming the files, I would have to rename all the references to those files as well. It would be considerable work and very difficult to test.